# How to create custom content type in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am new in Joomla.I want to create custom content type, I already use K2, but I need custom content type.
I already search for this i'm not able to find any solution.
I get different extensions but, i need my own custom.

Should i create : component , module or plugin for this?

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you are using K2 component,You can create multiple custom templates on it and assign those template to that content.

Reference : http://getk2.org/documentation/tutorials/174-templating-with-k2-and-the-concepts-of-sub-templates

Comment: I don't want to create template. Need to create new content type having administrator form. and display form value on front page.

Comment: create your own component add whatever field and style you want.